# How to assign keyboard shortcuts to multiple VBA macros

Tags: vba, excel

I've currently got a list of about 10 macros that each do something different. I basically would like to include VBA code in each of them (or as a separate list) which has the keyboard shortcut to activate each.

I know you can assign a shortcut when you create a macro in the options, but once you've saved the macro as an add-in and closed the file, you can no longer change the shortcut.

I've also tried the application.onkey function, but that only seems to work for 1 macro and I don't see how to add to the list.

Hopefully this makes sense but please ask for clarification if needed

Thanks,

Thomas

This is the code I'm using for the only Application.OnKey that works:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnKey "^+{\}", "IF_Error_Wrap"

End Sub

Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()
```

??????

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Just repeat the `Onkey` command for each macro/shortcut key combination.

Comment: Do i need to save and exit the workbook when I add them? For some reason it never seems to work

Comment: Yes - the `Open` event only fires when you first open the workbook. You should also have code in the `BeforeClose` to remove the assignments.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, I would put the BeforeClose just after End Sub? Also what should I put after before close? (I've added what I've got so far above)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the `OnKey` line for each assignment, and be sure to clear the shortcuts when the file closes using `BeforeClose` like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey "^+{\}"
End Sub
```

If it's an add-in, you could alternatively, and probably more safely, use the `Workbook_AddinUninstall()` event to clear the keys.